# Eclipse Helios, I'm “unable to connect to repository”

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I've installed Eclipse IDE for J2EE, now I'm trying to install WTP. 
I've tried every solution I could find here and else where..

There is no proxy issue because I could open the repository site through the internal web browser.

I've tried adding "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = true" to eclipse.ini.

I've tried clearing cache, a different workspace...
I'm a complete newbie, by the way. Just in case I've missed something obvious.

**Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/content.xml,** 
is the error I'm getting!

If it of any help, here is the stack strace for that error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.events.socket.SocketEventCreateUtil.createSocket(SocketEventCreateUtil.java:43)
at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:81)
at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:73)
at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:65) 
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:227)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: You installed Helios? Why not a more recent one?

Comment: Downloading a new one isn't feasible right now. It worked well at home

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Apparently, that repository is deprecated. You may want to try a repo associated with a new version of eclipse e.g. Juno.</strike>

Oh, wait. I think your link was wrong.

> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/

Try using this as **Work with:**

Furthermore, [isn't this what you're looking for](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/)?

Comment: I have been using the same. Reloading the same on preferences->install/update says that, "This repository is currently not available". I believe you were right earlier.

Comment: @Thushar Even the actual website throws a 404. Usually that means the repo has been deleted. If it would be there, then you would see a message like "This is the repository site for bla bla bla, use with Eclipse Install New Software".

Comment: hmmmm.. So, my only option is to download Juno?

Comment: @Thushar First, try using a newer repo. A Juno or Kepler repository. Your last resort is downloading a newer IDE.

Comment: @CGrec Unable to connect to Juno or Kepler repositories either. What could be the reason?

Comment: @Thushar What links did you use?

Comment: @CGrec this-- download.eclipse.org/releases/juno ... I downloaded juno, I would still love to know what went wrong.

Comment: @Thushar I'm going to stick to my initial solution: the repo is deprecated. :-) Good luck.